# Design suggestion required in UITableView Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I just need a suggestion to Implement tableView for the application. 
According to reference image is this a collectionView used in tableView? 
Actually I want to implement 4 views on the top of the tableView something like Reminder app of apple. Obviously not to copy design but I need 4 views within UITableView.
These 4 views are also scrollable as its the part of tableview.

- I am confused in this how can I achieve this design image attached.
- my main concern is 4 top views tile style.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXyss.jpg)

Comment: Do you want the 4 top views to scroll along with the table view or to always appear?

Comment: @HalR  scroll along with tableview.

Comment: 1.create 2 custom cell cells for your table view. 2. split the table view in 2 sections. 3. first section will have one type of custom cell that is the 4 views you want. 4. second section will have the other custom cell as per design. just an idea

Answer (score 0):

In your case you may better use `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView` and set your "reminder" view as `tableHeaderView`:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myReminderView
```

If you need to implement it as a cell, for some reasons, just create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and add `UICollectionView` with all DataSources/Delegates implementations you need inside this cell class.